# Как оптимально обойти все вершины графа?

Tags: графы, алгоритм

С помощью какого алгоритма можно найти кратчайший (с min суммой весов дуг) путь, проходящий через все вершины графа?

Подойдет ли [алгоритм Дейкстры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%EB%E3%EE%F0%E8%F2%EC_%C4%E5%E9%EA%F1%F2%F0%FB)?

Comment: Что такое "кратчайший путь" в вашем случае? Общее количество пройденных рёбер?

Comment: Кратчайший путь - путь пройденный через все вершины графа, сумма весов дуг которых минимален

Comment: Дейкстра не подойдёт — он не гарантирует обход всех вершин.

Comment: Какой подойдет?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это задача поиска гамильтонового пути, причём она NP-полная.
Если нужен точный алгоритм при небольшом (максимум в районе 20-25) количестве вершин, то есть решение с помощью динамического программирования, который работает быстрее перебора: http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/337

При большем кол-ве вершин задача уже решается приближенными (жадность, "муравьиность") алгоритмами: http://habrahabr.ru/post/160077/